# Pyspark. Join two df by string in text

Tags: python, pyspark

- 1 df contains text
- 2 df contains words and its rate

I need to join those two dfs and sum rate

---

-I've tried:

`df_joined = df_text.join(df_words, f.expr("text rlike word"), 'left')`

-or

`df_joined = df_text.join(df_words, on=df_text.text.contains(df_words.word),how='left')`

---

But it finds part of word too (e.g - df_words contains "slow" and "slowly", and if "slowly" is in text, two rates joins, but I need only one - "slowly").

Any suggestions?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine)

```
split_col = f.split(df_text['text'], ' ')

df_text = df_text.withColumn('txt_split', split_col)

df_join = df_text.withColumn('word', f.explode("txt_split").alias("word"))\
    .join(df_words, "word", 'left')
```